# How to check when the user is logged out by session expiration

Tags: jsf, glassfish, httpsession

I have JSF web app on glassfish using j_security_check validation with jdbcRealm on glassfish connected to MSSQL db.
Is there any way to check for example if there exists active bean with given username?
I just want to display on the web page who is online. My guesses:

1. keep variable in database and change it with login/logout. The problem rather occurs if someone didnt logout but his session expires. Than I don't have possibility to check if he's still logged in.
2. keep boolean variable in bean and change it with login/logout. Problem is as in previous opportunity.

Is there way to change such variable while session expires? Maybe some other approach is more common?

Comment: why not make a boolean field for online in the member database, and when their session expires set it to false?

Comment: This is something i've been considering but I don't know how to check if someones session has expired, or how to change variable paralelly to such expiration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> *The problem rather occurs if someone didnt logout but his session expires. Than I don't have possibility to check if he's still logged in.*

You have the possibility by implementing a [`HttpSessionListener`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpSessionListener.html):

```
@WebListener
public class YourUserSessionListener implements HttpSessionListener {

    @Override 
    public void sessionCreated(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        // NOOP.
    }

    @Override
    public void sessionDestroyed(HttpSessionEvent event) {
        YourUser yourUser = event.getSession().getAttribute("yourUser");

        if (yourUser != null) {
            yourUser.logout(); // Update DB.
        }
    }

}
```

Where `YourUser` is your session scoped JSF managed bean representing the logged-in user.

Or when you're on JSF2 (as your question history confirms), put [`@PreDestroy`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/annotation/PreDestroy.html) on the logout method in the session scoped JSF managed bean representing the logged-in user:

```
@ManagedBean
@SessionScoped
public class YourUser {

    // ...

    @PreDestroy
    public void logout() {
        // Update DB.
    }

}
```

This way the method will be invoked before the bean get destroyed on session expiration.